# Ontology Alignment vs. Ontology Mapping

Tags: rdf, terminology, owl, ontology

I am quite new to this research area. I am interested in the subtle differences between what is meant by "alignment" and what is meant by "mapping" in the context of Ontology Matching.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: *alignment* is the process, *mapping* is the outcome of the process.

Comment: *Ontology matching* is the process, an *ontology alignment* is a result of the process execution. (according to Euzenat, Shvaiko: *Ontology Matching, Second Edition*, Springer 2013).

Comment: It is normal that you are confused. In the literature on the topic, people tend to use ontology matching, ontology alignment, ontology mapping, in different ways, sometimes interchangeably, sometimes with subtle nuances. Thanks to the book *Ontology Matching*, first published in 2007, the vocabulary tends to cristalise to what I said in my previous comment. I do not remember how the term "ontology mapping" is defined there, if it is at all.